# How to create muti-pages forms in Android Studio

Tags: firebase, android-studio, user-interface, android-fragments, android-intent

I am a newbie sweating to develop my first app on android studio. I want to build a multi-page user sign up form, each page corresponding to one data info about the user. For example:

1. User_name: page asking the user to type in his name
2. User_age: asking the user to type in his age
3. And so on

And in the end collect all that info and create a user profile in firebase.

My question is: what are the components that can be used for this?

I have tried intents with putExtras and getExtra. But it is tedious and requires a lot of iteration. Not sure if this is an ideal solution.

So what else do you guys have?

Looking forward to your contributions.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have only one activity and use different fragments. In each fragment you ask info to the user and each one has a reference to the main activity so you can easily collect all data in the main activity.

I ususally do this by having the layout of my activity consisting of only one big empty layout(here its id is main_container)

Then my activity has a function that loads fragment on the layout

```
public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.main_container,fragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Now you only need to create fragments. Ex you have a NameFragment that ask user's name. In it you have a function setActivity to set a reference to the main activity.
Then in onCreate of the Activity you can use

```
    NameFragment fragment=new NameFragment(); //here if your fragment needs paramenters you
    // can create a static method newInstance and save them in a bundle
    fragment.setActivity(this);
    loadFragment(fragment);
```

which will load this fragment as first one. Then from NameFragment you can ask the name, use the reference to the activity to save it and using the same reference you can also load another fragment

note: I didn't want to confuse you but you can create an interface with setActivity, implement it in every fragment and make loadFragment take that interface as paramether so you can call the method inside loadFragment instead of outside